# Which swing components to use

Tags: java, swing

Can you tell me which Java components I should use to achieve the same result as on picture?[image]

After clicking on the link FileChooser is opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`JEditorPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) with HTML markup inside.

You'll have to add a `HyperlinkListener` to trigger some action when the link is clicked.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What is this link? Is it a button? How can I add it to the Pane?

Comment: You can add it using HTML markup. The whole content could be a small HTML page, with a hyperlink inside it: <a href="...">Click here</a>

Comment: Can I set text by hand or I have to load it from URL? When I use setText() it simply displays the a href

Comment: Read the javadoc for this component: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html. You must use setContentType("text/html") to make it parse the text as HTML.

Comment: Hello, please look at the question again. Event is not fired, when I click on the link..

Comment: Have you made the editor pane not editable? From the javadoc: "The HTML EditorKit will generate hyperlink events if the JEditorPane is not editable". Please read the javadoc before asking questions. Most of the answers are in the javadoc.

Comment: For Christ sake, read the javadoc: It has an example: if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {. The other types of events are ENTERED and EXITED. It's the third time you're asking a question for something that can be found in 10 seconds by just reading the javadoc of the class. And it's the third time I ask you to read the javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a dialog. Either a generic [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), or undecorated [`JDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). You can then decorate a `JLabel` to look like a hyperlink, and then register a `MouserListener` that will open the `JFileChooser`.

Comment: that correct answer for me JWindow(un-decorated JDialog)/JOptionPane/JDialog with my logics ordering for that +1, interesting link @Suraj Chandran +1

Answer (score 1):

1. The background could be a JPanel within a JDialog or JFrame
2. Use JLabel as an image to show the icon "i".
3. Use JLabel as the hyperlink for "Click here". See [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/340009/GUI/java/add-hyperlink) for how achieve hyperlink with JLabel
4. Add an action to the label to open JFileChooser.

Comment: A `JLabel` doesn't generate action events.

Comment: see the link i have in my answer for how to achieve it: http://www.coderanch.com/t/340009/GUI/java/add-hyperlink

Comment: Where should I put retained text? If I put it inside first one, then I don't know when to open the FileChooser.

Comment: @Suraj, That's a mouse event, not an action event.

Comment: @mre i know, when i said action, i meant code, didnt mean action in the same sense as ActionListener

Comment: @Suraj, Oh, then in that case, you should have said "event listener"